# Резиновая высота блока

Tags: css

Имеется блок в котором блок с новостью выровненный по левому краю и блок с превьюшками выровненный по правому краю.Блоки внутри блока удалось отформатировать,но увы задний фон родительского блока не удаётся задать,фиксированная высота помогает,но дело в том что блоков будет неизвестное количество и при добавлении новых хотелось бы что-бы фон родительского блока расширялся.Пробовал задавать 100% высоте,но не работает (html, body{height:100%} пробовал}.Так-же прочитал что блок автоматически должен расширяться и задавать ему высоту вовсе не обязательно,но у меня не понятное что-то,не работает.

```
    <div class="main_container">
            <div class="right_nav" >
        <div class="preview">
            <ul>
                            <li class="right_preview"><p class="preview_article">Article_1</p><a><img src="slide_230.png" alt="preview_image"></a></li>
                            <li class="right_preview"><p class="preview_article">Article_2</p><a><img src="slide_230.png" alt="preview_image"></a></li>
                            <li class="right_preview"><p class="preview_article">Article_3</p><a><img src="slide_230.png" alt="preview_image"></a></li>
                            <li class="right_preview"><p class="preview_article">Article_4</p><a><img src="slide_230.png" alt="preview_image"></a></li>
                            <li class="right_preview"><p class="preview_article">Article_5</p><a><img src="slide_230.png" alt="preview_image"></a></li>
                        </ul>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <h1>NEWS1</h1>
        <h2>02.Октября.2015</h2>
        <div class="news_container_img">
            <img src="slide_674.png" alt="news_image">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non aperiam, perspiciatis nobis blanditiis ratione obcaecati quisquam dignissimos voluptas iusto, quos cumque? Cupiditate commodi ipsam rerum itaque, aliquam, illum minus iusto, consequatur magni recusandae voluptas. Amet aliquid dicta sequi ipsum debitis ab excepturi eos impedit? Excepturi, quas, iste? Nisi expedita fugiat voluptatum odit, eveniet necessitatibus delectus atque molestiae sit architecto ducimus et maiores odio error, nam nulla tempore voluptatem temporibus dolorem sed saepe quaerat optio voluptas. Sapiente quam, nesciunt ut dicta...</p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <h1>NEWS1</h1>
        <h2>02.Октября.2015</h2>
        <div class="news_container_img">
            <img src="slide_674.png" alt="news_image">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non aperiam, perspiciatis nobis blanditiis ratione obcaecati quisquam dignissimos voluptas iusto, quos cumque? Cupiditate commodi ipsam rerum itaque, aliquam, illum minus iusto, consequatur magni recusandae voluptas. Amet aliquid dicta sequi ipsum debitis ab excepturi eos impedit? Excepturi, quas, iste? Nisi expedita fugiat voluptatum odit, eveniet necessitatibus delectus atque molestiae sit architecto ducimus et maiores odio error, nam nulla tempore voluptatem temporibus dolorem sed saepe quaerat optio voluptas. Sapiente quam, nesciunt ut dicta...</p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css: по ссылке ниже (извиняюсь,не нашёл способа как запостить css в облаке кода,прошу модераторов исправить если что-то не так).

http://jsfiddle.net/903jwL1q/

з.ы. - Огромная просьба не кидаться испорченными предметами за грязный код,я и сам всё знаю.

Comment: Если float:left убрать у новостей, то фон растянется. Правда там проблемы с выходом ссылок за новость появляется.

Comment: Да,получилось сделать растягивающийся фон,большое спасибо.На счёт ссылок:добавил их в заголовок и задал класс,как правильнее будет сделать?
http://jsfiddle.net/48u4nkmr/